# prove that the following function is: $f(x) = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ , $f$ is differentiable
>
> $f(0) = 0$
>
> $|f'(x)|\le|f(x)|$ for $x\in [0,1]$
>
> prove that $f(x) =0$ for $x\in [0,1]$

i believe that i need to somehow use the mean value theorem iteratively

any hints?

Comment: What if $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in [0,1]$?

Comment: @JPLF: $f(0) = 0$ is a given.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't read carefully.

Comment: If this is showing up in a differential equations context, look up Gronwall's inequality.

Comment: So, $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 0$. Surely, to rise above $0$, $f$ needs a positive derivative. But it can't have a positive derivative as long as it is $0$.

Comment: Wow! Somebody **really** is posting all the last exercises from the Calculus I homework in the Tel-Aviv University Mathematics Dept ...

Comment: Oh, I didn't "find it", @GinKin :I know it first hand... :)

Comment: @DonAntonio Plot twist: you're actually one of the professors here.

Comment: Oh, no @GinKin : not a professor *there* ...

Comment: Don't sweat over that, @GinKin. It really isn't important. What's more important is that quite a few of those exercises in that precise targil No. 12 appeared here, and nothing wrong with that *unless* some self effort isn't made to solve them, which seems to be lacking from some questions...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Choose $x \in [0,1]$. By the mean-value theorem,
$$f(x) = f(x) - f(0) = f'(c)(x-0) = f'(c)x$$

for some $c \in (0,x)$. But
$$|f'(c)x| \leq |f(c)||x| = |f(c) - f(0)||x| \leq |f'(d)||x||c| \leq |f'(d)||x|^2$$

for some $d \in (0,c)$. Do you see how to iterate this argument?

---

More hints:

> Note that $f$ is continuous and hence bounded on the compact set $[0,1]$, and by the hypothesis that $|f'| \leq |f|$, $f'$ is also bounded.

---

> Iterate the above to show $|f(x)| \leq M |x|^n$ for some absolute constant $M$ and all $n$.

---

> Conclude that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1)$. To obtain the result at $1$, either use the continuity of $f(x)$, or the following argument: you now know that $f(0.5) = 0$, so repeat the above argument, but center it at $0.5$ instead of $0$. You should get some bound $f(1) \leq M |1 - 0.5|^n$.

Comment: Ah, right. That's not a hypothesis. Let me adjust the proof.

Comment: Now it's fine and rather nice. +1

Comment: @IsaacSolomon what does it mean to iterate an argument in math or to prove in an iterative way ? I suppose it's different from induction.

Comment: @GinKin Perhaps a good definition would be that an "iterative argument" is one that reduces to applying the same step over and over. In this case, obtaining the bound $|f(x)| \leq M|x|^n$ for all $n$ requires induction, because I am trying to prove a statement about all natural numbers. However, it is possible to complete the proof without induction, by supposing that $|f(x)| \geq \epsilon > 0$ and obtaining a contradiction by iterating until $M|x|^N < \epsilon$ for some sufficiently large $N$.